# SSIS composite key

Tags: ssis

My SSIS packages pulls data from a databsse X to my local database. Here is the situation. The incoming data has 3 columns: `colA`, `colB`, `colC` none of them have  Primary key and uniqueness. I used joins to get `columnA` from another table. These columns are in look up with my table columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3`. Both `Col1`, `Col2` are primary keys.

```
colA    colB   colC
100       1     1000.00
100       2     500.00
...
100       5      1500.00
200       1       500.00
....
200       6      5678.00
...
```

I shoudn't use colC as the look up column. How to pull data from databse X to my databse?
Plz..I am new to SSIS.

Comment: Put some actual tables in this question please. Help us understand the problem. Given the above data, what's a sample of the reference data? What should the final result set look like?